# Data Inserted But Return False in CodeIgniter 4

Tags: php, codeigniter-4

I tried to insert data to database using model. The data inserted but the method `$model->insert($data)` return false.
This is my table schema (took it from my migration) :

```
 $this->forge->addField([
            'penyakit_kode' => [
                'type' => 'VARCHAR',
                'constraint' => '3'
            ],
            'penyakit_nama' => [
                'type' => 'VARCHAR',
                'constraint' => '100',
            ],
            'penyakit_detail' => [
                'type' => 'TEXT',
            ],
            'penyakit_solusi' => [
                'type' => 'TEXT',
            ],
        ]);
$this->forge->addPrimaryKey('penyakit_kode');
$this->forge->createTable('penyakit');
```

my model :

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use CodeIgniter\Model;

class PenyakitModel extends Model
{
    protected $DBGroup          = 'default';
    protected $table            = 'penyakit';
    protected $primaryKey       = 'penyakit_kode';
    protected $useAutoIncrement = true;
    protected $insertID         = 0;
    protected $returnType       = 'object';
    protected $useSoftDeletes   = false;
    protected $protectFields    = true;
    protected $allowedFields    = [
        'penyakit_kode',
        'penyakit_nama',
        'penyakit_detail',
        'penyakit_solusi'
    ];

    // Dates
    protected $useTimestamps = false;
    protected $dateFormat    = 'datetime';
    protected $createdField  = 'created_at';
    protected $updatedField  = 'updated_at';
    protected $deletedField  = 'deleted_at';

    // Validation
    protected $validationRules      = [
        'penyakit_kode' => 'required|is_unique[penyakit.penyakit_kode]',
        'penyakit_nama' => 'required',
        'penyakit_detail' => 'required',
        'penyakit_solusi' => 'required',
    ];
    protected $validationMessages   = [];
    protected $skipValidation       = false;
    protected $cleanValidationRules = true;

    // Callbacks
    protected $allowCallbacks = true;
    protected $beforeInsert   = [];
    protected $afterInsert    = [];
    protected $beforeUpdate   = [];
    protected $afterUpdate    = [];
    protected $beforeFind     = [];
    protected $afterFind      = [];
    protected $beforeDelete   = [];
    protected $afterDelete    = [];
}
```

and my insert method :

```
public function store()
    {
        $data = $this->request->getPost();
        $model = new PenyakitModel();

        if ($model->insert($data)) {
            return redirect()->to(session('user')->user_type . '/penyakit')
                ->with('success', 'Data Penyakit berhasil disimpan!!');
        } else {
            return redirect()->back()
                ->with('errors', $model->errors())
                ->with('danger', 'Periksa kembali data penyakit!')
                ->withInput();
        }
    }
```

The field `penyakit_kode` is manually inserted.

It returns error message when insert, but data recorded on the database.

I don't really know why this happened. I'm hoping that any of you could spot the error and give me the best solution.
Thank You in advanced.

Comment: What is in `var_dump($this->request->getPost());`?

Comment: *'It returns error message when insert, ....'* Please share that specific returned error message here as well.

Answer (score 0):

Take out the line `protected $createdField  = 'created_at';` - you don't have that field on the table and see if that works. If that fails, hack Codeigniter `insert()` as there is an $sql variable which if you output and exit will give you the full query. You can then run that in a DB tool and see what the database error says. Thats how I resolved a very similar issue.